# How can i make my model count ticks faster vs the actions they are doing using NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm modeling a critical situation that's happening in my city (Viña del Mar, Chile), where the "metro" (subway)can have serious problems if a tsunami occurs because the evacuation exits are not well prepared nor well managed.

This example is a simple model of the real one, but i was having really big problems trying to make the turtles move from the subway (blue patches), using the door (lime patch) and then jumping into the railways (gray patches). When i finally made them do those actions i found 2 problems: (1) the ticks aren't working the way i need them to work. I need it to run like it was a clock, counting seconds. (2) i create 3 actions called "check-vecinos-azul/lime/gray" where they need to check if there's any turtle arround them (neighbors). If there's an empty space arround a turtle it moves to that empty spot, otherwise it stands until it finds an empty one.

I'd be so glad if anyone of you could give me a help/tip with my model.

Thank you guys,

Kind regards,

Felipe.

```
breed [pasajeros pasajero]

turtles-own [
   distancia
   speed
   speed-limit
   speed-min
  evacuacion
]

patches-own
[
  pvacio
]

to setup
  ca
  setup-patches
  setup-pasajeros
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches with [pycor <= 0]
  [set pcolor blue - 1]
  ask patches with [pycor > 0]
  [set pcolor gray + 2]
  ask patch 0 0 [set pcolor lime]
end

to setup-pasajeros
  ask n-of num-pasajeros (patches with [pcolor = blue - 1])
  [
    sprout-pasajeros 1
    [set size 1
     set color orange
     set speed 0.1 + random-float 0.9
     set speed-limit 1
     set speed-min 0
     set evacuacion 0
    ]
  ]
end

to go
 ask pasajeros [
    ifelse evacuar?
    [
      go-puerta
      salir-puerta
      move-chancado
    ]
    [
      stop
    ]
  ]
  tick 
end

 to go-puerta
  ask turtles with [pcolor = blue - 1]
  [
    set evacuacion 1
    if evacuacion = 1
    [
      check-vecinos-azul
      face min-one-of patches with [pcolor = lime][distance myself]
      fd speed                                                         ;;
    ]
  ]
end

to salir-puerta
  ask turtles with [pcolor = lime]
  [
    set evacuacion 1
    if evacuacion = 1
    [
      check-vecinos-lime
      face min-one-of patches with [pcolor = gray + 2][distance myself]
      fd speed
    ]
  ]
end

to move-chancado
  ask turtles with [pcolor = gray + 2]
  [
    set evacuacion 1
    check-vecinos-gray
  ]
end

to check-vecinos-azul
  ifelse not any? turtles-on one-of neighbors
  [
    wait 0
    move-to min-one-of patches with [pcolor = blue - 1][distance myself]
    fd speed
  ]
  [
    wait 0.5
  ]
end

to check-vecinos-lime
  ifelse not any? turtles-on one-of neighbors
  [
    wait 0
    face one-of patches with [pcolor = gray + 2]
    fd speed
  ]
  [
    wait 0.5
  ]
end

to check-vecinos-gray
  ifelse not any? turtles-on one-of neighbors
  [
    wait 0
    face min-one-of patches with [pcolor = gray + 2][distance myself]
    fd speed
  ]
  [
    wait 0.5
  ] 
end
```

Comment: if you have 2 questions, please ask them separately. when you ask the neighbors question, please explain what's actually wrong - for example, is an error message being generated (and, if so, what does the message say), or what is the behaviour you want compared to the behaviour you are getting.

Comment: with regard to the question about ticks and seconds, that is not how NetLogo works. A tick indicates the next round of activity. You can certainly interpret ticks as seconds and then have activities occur at appropriate intervals. For example, you may move agents whatever distance they would be expected to move in a second.

Comment: Thank you JenB. I'll consider your comment next time i post.

First of all, and talking about the neighbors question, i need each turtle to check if there's an empty spot arrount it (neighbors). If it finds an empty spot (or more than 1) it'd move to one of them. In case the 8 neighbors are occupied by more turtles, it stops and wait for an empty spot until it reaches the door (patch lime) to exit de subway. Same thing happens when it moves into the lime patch and has to decide to which gray patch shall it moves.

Comment: Second, and about the tick issue. I didn't understand that good what you tried to explain. Do you have any model or example to understand better what you jost replied me?

Thank you very much for your support JenB.